# Media Query Running When Resizing Browser But Not In Mobile View

Tags: media-queries

Media Query Running When Resizing Browser But Not In Chromes Mobile View Or When opening On Mobile.

Here's the media query i'm using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
.date {
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
}}
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This meta tag was missing in the head

```
<meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```